# Crear gifs con iphone de poco peso para web

Tags: html, web, gif

Buenas tardes

Tengo un proyecto de un sistema para un gimnasio donde la ejecución de los ejercicios se puede ver en un gif animado, y ya esta funcionando, el problema es que los gifs que realice son muy pesados , algunos pesan 1.8mb por lo cual el sistema se demora en cargar, quisiera saber si alguien sabe como puedo hacer gifs con la camara del iphone 6 pero que pesen muy poco, en una pagina similar vi gifs que pesaban 20kb que es algo sumamente bajo. si alguien me puede ayudar les agradezco mucho

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque no trata sobre programación dentro del alcance definido en el [centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

Una de las grandes pegas de los **GIFs es que hay que recurrir a la pérdida de calidad para disminuir su peso**.

Existen muchas web on-line que te permiten reducir entre un 30-40% del peso del GIF que tengas.

Por ejemplo:
http://www.iloveimg.com/es/comprimir-imagen/comprimir-gif

*También puedes considerar usar el formato PNG* que tambien soporta animación y permite reducir tambien el tamaño con menos perdida de calidad.